# When range is > 30 days MYSQL is filtering results out

Tags: mysql

If I run a query between June 1st and June 30th I'll get 23 results. If I run a query between July 1st and July 31st I'll get 28 results. If I run a query from June 1st to July 31st I only get 30 results. Why is this?

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
    table1.user_id,
    DATE_FORMAT(table1.timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d') AS formatted_timestamp,
    COUNT(DISTINCT table1.call_id) as calls,
    SUM(table2.recording_file_duration) / 60 as minutes,
    hours.hours
FROM
    table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON
    table1.call_id = table2.id
LEFT JOIN table3 ON
    table1.user_id = table3.accountID
    AND
    DATE_FORMAT(table1.timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d') = table3.date
WHERE
    table1.user_id = '244'
    AND
    table1.timestamp >= '$dateStart' and table1.timestamp < '$dateEnd'
GROUP BY
    DAY(table1.timestamp)
ORDER BY
    table1.timestamp DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your `group by` condition:

```
GROUP BY DAY(table1.timestamp)
```

It is aggregating by the day of the month, so June 10th and July 10th will be combined.

Try this:

```
GROUP BY MONTH(table1.timestamp), DAY(table1.timestamp)
```

or

```
GROUP BY DATE(table1.timestamp)
```

I think the latter is the best solution.  This converts the field into the date (with no time component).